# AppActivate not sending keys or truly activating

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I have an Appactivate VBA script to open a program and then send keys to login. It worked flawlessly for years and since the program got update it does not seem to work anymore. The issue is the appactivate actually pulls the window up but it does not send any keys. The password section does not show the blinking cursor until I actually click on the window with my mouse. Is their another way to activate the window/program? The code is below.

```
Sub LOGIN()

Shell ("C:\ASD\ASDF.exe")

 Dim PASS As String


 PASS = Range("D11")

    AppActivate ("ASDF")
    'THIS IS WHERE IT STOPS. THE WINDOW POPS UP. THE CODE DOES NOT ERROR ITS JUST DOESN'T SEND ANY KEYS AFTER THIS BECAUSE I THINK THE WINDOW IS TRULY NOT ACTIVE.
    Application.SendKeys "+{TAB 4}"
    Application.SendKeys "FACILITY NAME"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB 4}"
    Application.SendKeys PASS
    Application.SendKeys vbCrLf

End Sub
```

Comment: "ASDF" needs to match the window you're looking for. If the app was updated and instead of "ASDF" it now says "ASDF 2.0", likely your code needs to update that.

Comment: It matches correctly. I only changed it to that to hide the program name. It actually pops the window in front and seems like the appActivate works. It just doesn't type any of the sendkeys. Before AppActivate would bring the window to the front and the typing cursor will blink at password. Now it brings it to the front but does not have a cursor in any of the boxes to type in.

Comment: I'd try using Win32 API calls instead of `Application.SendKeys`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897489/1188513) should help.