# How can I use SendInput function in VBA to combine keystrokes for Chrome window?

Tags: vba, windows, winapi

I want to use Sendinput function of Windows API in VBA to send a combination of keystrokes to  a window, for example Ctrl H to Chrome. I choose sendinput() because sendmessage would not allow me to send a combination of key at the same time, the window will receive them seperately. On the other hand, the SendKeys method in VBA is said to be unreliable.

So after read the documentation and google search, I reach to this code

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal hWndChild As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias _
    "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpWindowText As String, ByVal nMaxCount As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias _
    "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)


Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendInput Lib "user32" ( _
         ByVal nInputs As LongPtr, _
         ByRef pInputs As Any, _
         ByVal cbSize As LongPtr) As Long

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1
Private Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
Private Const VK_RETURN As Integer = &HD
Private Const WM_CHAR As Long = &H102
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Long = &H100
Private Const WM_KEYUP As Long = &H101
Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN As Long = &H104
Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP As Long = &H105
Private Const VK_LBUTTON As Long = &H1
Private Const VK_RBUTTON As Long = &H2
Private Const VK_CANCEL As Long = &H3
Private Const VK_MBUTTON As Long = &H4
Private Const VK_XBUTTON1 As Long = &H5
Private Const VK_XBUTTON2 As Long = &H6
Private Const VK_BACKSPACE As Long = &H8
Private Const VK_TAB As Long = &H9 'TAB
Private Const VK_CLEAR As Long = &HC
Private Const VK_ENTER As Long = &HD
Private Const VK_SHIFT As Long = &H10
Private Const VK_CONTROL As Long = &H11 'CTRL
Private Const VK_MENU As Long = &H12
Private Const VK_PAUSE As Long = &H13
Private Const VK_CAPSLOCK As Long = &H14
Private Const VK_ESCAPE As Long = &H1B
Private Const VK_SPACE As Long = &H20
Private Const VK_PAGEUP As Long = &H21
Private Const VK_PAGEDOWN As Long = &H22
Private Const VK_END As Long = &H23
Private Const VK_HOME As Long = &H24
Private Const VK_LEFT As Long = &H25
Private Const VK_UP As Long = &H26
Private Const VK_RIGHT As Long = &H27
Private Const VK_DOWN As Long = &H28
Private Const VK_PRINTSCREEN As Long = &H2C
Private Const VK_INSERT As Long = &H2D
Private Const VK_DELETE As Long = &H2E
Private Const VK_0 As Long = &H30
Private Const VK_1 As Long = &H31
Private Const VK_2 As Long = &H32
Private Const VK_3 As Long = &H33
Private Const VK_4 As Long = &H34
Private Const VK_5 As Long = &H35
Private Const VK_6 As Long = &H36
Private Const VK_7 As Long = &H37
Private Const VK_8 As Long = &H38
Private Const VK_9 As Long = &H39
Private Const VK_A As Long = &H41
Private Const VK_B As Long = &H42
Private Const VK_C As Long = &H43
Private Const VK_D As Long = &H44
Private Const VK_E As Long = &H45
Private Const VK_F As Long = &H46
Private Const VK_G As Long = &H47
Private Const VK_H As Long = &H48
Private Const VK_I As Long = &H49
Private Const VK_J As Long = &H4A
Private Const VK_K As Long = &H4B
Private Const VK_L As Long = &H4C
Private Const VK_M As Long = &H4D
Private Const VK_N As Long = &H4E
Private Const VK_O As Long = &H4F
Private Const VK_P As Long = &H50
Private Const VK_Q As Long = &H51
Private Const VK_R As Long = &H52
Private Const VK_S As Long = &H53
Private Const VK_T As Long = &H54
Private Const VK_U As Long = &H55
Private Const VK_V As Long = &H56
Private Const VK_W As Long = &H57
Private Const VK_X As Long = &H58
Private Const VK_Y As Long = &H59
Private Const VK_Z As Long = &H5A
Private Const VK_F11 = &H7A
Private Const INPUT_KEYBOARD As Long = 1
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Long = 2

Const GW_CHILD = 5
Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Dim keyInput()    As INPUT_
Dim sizeINPUT     As Long

Private Type INPUT_      '   typedef struct tagINPUT {
    dwType As Long                '     DWORD type;
    wVK As Integer                '     union {MOUSEINPUT mi;
    wScan As Integer              '               KEYBDINPUT ki;
    dwFlags As Long               '               HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    dwTime As LongPtr                '              };
    dwExtraInfo As LongPtr            '     }INPUT, *PINPUT;
    dwPadding As Currency         '   8 extra bytes, because mouses take more.
End Type

Sub main() ' {
    
    sizeINPUT = LenB(keyInput(0))
    Call SendKeystrokeFromExcel
    Call Sleep(100)
    Call Ctrl_H
    


End Sub ' }



Sub SendKeystrokeFromExcel()
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    ' Find the window by its title
    hWnd = 1378908 'Handle of Google Chrome
    ShowWindow hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL
    SetForegroundWindow hWnd
    Sleep (100)
    SendMessage hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F11, 0

End Sub

Sub Ctrl_H() 

    ReDim keyInput(0 To 3)

    keyInput(0).dwType = INPUT_KEYBOARD
    keyInput(0).dwFlags = 0        ' Press key
    keyInput(0).wVK = VK_CONTROL

    keyInput(1).dwType = INPUT_KEYBOARD
    keyInput(1).dwFlags = 0        ' Press key
    keyInput(1).wVK = VK_H

    keyInput(2).dwType = INPUT_KEYBOARD
    keyInput(2).dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP
    keyInput(2).wVK = VK_H

    keyInput(3).dwType = INPUT_KEYBOARD
    keyInput(3).dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP
    keyInput(3).wVK = VK_CONTROL
    Call SendInput(4, keyInput(0), sizeINPUT)

End Sub
```

So when I run the code, it found the Chrome windows easily. However when it comes to run the SUB Ctrl_H(), it seems that it cant be run even enormous the amount of work I put in. All the code I found in the internet, include in stack exchange ([SendInput VB Basic Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896658/sendinput-vb-basic-example)) won't work . If anyone have any solution, I would be really aprreciate.

Comment: You cannot use `SendInput` to target a particular window. Instead, you'll want to use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) as a robust alternative to faking input.

Comment: My mistake for not pointing that out. I have used setforegroundwindow and showwindow  already, at first I try to do it using sendmessage but it does not support multiple keys sent at the same time. Ui automation is seem unlikely to fit my pupose because my job is done on a corporate computer, which has many restriction. Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: Did you actually try? It is very, *very* unlikely for a system to have a policy that disables UI Automation.

Comment: On a second thought, it would be a possibility I would try. Thank you for your suggestion. Anyway, is UI Automation is the best for Automate using VBA ? Is there other methods that I should consider ?

Comment: `dwTime` should be a Long - and `keyInput` and `sizeINPUT` should definetly be not global in scope. They should be scoped to the appropriate procedure, there is no need for them to be globally accessible so they shouldn't

Comment: your Declare is off - cbSize get's passed as A Long (it's a size after all not a pointer or handle) the same goes for nInputs (you know when to use PtrSafe, right?) - pInputs does not have the type any - the type of pInputs is INPUT_

Comment: UI Automation is the first option you should consider when attempting to automate a task. It is immune against changes in keyboard settings across user profiles or languages, doesn't require the target to be the foreground window (or even visible), and reports the outcome of the operation. Simulating keyboard input falls short on all of those.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the Declarations and Types in a recent project of mine - they work and have been tested. (Starting with something like `CtrlH` is pretty risky if you don't know if your declarations even work. CtrlH couldn't yield your desired result for a multitude of reasons - I would suggest you start with something like typing one character into notepad (in order to test if the declarations work) - Just set a sleep timer for 5 sec before you call sendinput for the character key press, select notepad manually and see what happens (this way you elimante other factors that could be the issue)

Maybe the issue is the Declarations, maybe it is the activation of the window, maybe it is something with CtrlH itself, By testing everything at once you won't really be able to see what works and what might be causing issues.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMouseInput Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendInput" (ByVal cInputs As Long, ByRef pInputs As tagINPUT_mouse, ByVal cbSize As Integer) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendKeybdInput Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendInput" (ByVal cInputs As Long, ByRef pInputs As tagINPUT_keybd, ByVal cbSize As Integer) As Long

Type tagMOUSEINPUT
    dx As Long
    dy As Long
    mouseData As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As LongPtr
End Type

Type tagKEYBDINPUT
    wVk As Integer
    wScan As Integer
    dwFlags As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As LongPtr
    padding As Currency 'adding 8bytes to get to same size as MOUSEINPUT (2bytes difference per parameter of type Int, and 4bytes for 1 less parameter)
End Type

Type tagINPUT_mouse
    INPUTTYPE As Long
    mi As tagMOUSEINPUT
End Type

Type tagINPUT_keybd
    INPUTTYPE As Long
    ki As tagKEYBDINPUT
End Type
```

Comment: Like you said, it works. Thank you so much. Your comment on my code did help too, even though I can't stick to my old code. I wrote a new code base on your declaration and input definition

Comment: One question, which books or materials should I read to understand or to use the Windows  API properly ?

Comment: @LvLinh https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa383749(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN are the resources I usually use when working with winAPI. One important thing to realize is: "Windows API functions do not care about how you name your variables (or about your variables in general). All they care about is size and position in memory. (That's why using the right types is so important)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Lord-JulianXLII code, I have successfully writen a code that send input to Windows. Here is it for anyone who care

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMouseInput Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendInput" (ByVal cInputs As Long, ByRef pInputs As tagINPUT_mouse, ByVal cbSize As Integer) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendKeybdInput Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendInput" (ByVal cInputs As Long, ByRef pInputs As tagINPUT_keybd, ByVal cbSize As Integer) As Long

Type tagMOUSEINPUT
    dx As Long
    dy As Long
    mouseData As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As LongPtr
End Type

Type tagKEYBDINPUT
    wVk As Integer
    wScan As Integer
    dwFlags As Long
    time As Long
    dwExtraInfo As LongPtr
    padding As Currency 'adding 8bytes to get to same size as MOUSEINPUT (2bytes difference per parameter of type Int, and 4bytes for 1 less parameter)
End Type

Type tagINPUT_mouse
    INPUTTYPE As Long
    mi As tagMOUSEINPUT
End Type

Type tagINPUT_keybd
    INPUTTYPE As Long
    ki As tagKEYBDINPUT
End Type

Sub Ctrl_H()

   Dim inputArray(1 To 2) As tagINPUT_keybd
    
    ' Set up the first input structure for "Ctrl" key press
    inputArray(1).INPUTTYPE = 1 ' INPUT_KEYBOARD
    inputArray(1).ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL
    inputArray(1).ki.dwFlags = 0 ' Key press
    
    ' Set up the second input structure for "H" key press
    inputArray(2).INPUTTYPE = 1 ' INPUT_KEYBOARD
    inputArray(2).ki.wVk = VK_H
    inputArray(2).ki.dwFlags = 0 ' Key press
    
    ' Send the keydown events
    Call SendKeybdInput(2, inputArray(1), LenB(inputArray(1)))
    
    ' Set up the first input structure for "Ctrl" key release
    inputArray(1).ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ' Key release
    
    ' Set up the second input structure for "H" key release
    inputArray(2).ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ' Key release
    
    ' Send the keyup events
    Call SendKeybdInput(2, inputArray(1), LenB(inputArray(1)))
End Sub
```

It is, however, better start with UIautomation like @IInspectable suggested.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).