# Using PostMessage to Send a Control Key + Alpha to WordPad using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, wordpad

Regardless that discussion of this & similar issues are near ubiquitous, I am unable find a working solution... using PostMessage / SendMessage (because they send directly to designated hwnd (unlike SendInput or Sendkeys).  There are a small minority of postings that suggest it cannot be done, but so many conversations on HOW to send a simple CNTL + 'U', for example, to WordPad.  At this point, I would even welcome a definitive IT CAN'T BE DONE.

Running Windows7, MS Office 2016

Have succesfully sent Text to WordPad using:
WM_KEYDOWN=&H100, _KEYUP=&H101, _CHAR=&H102
vbKEYCONTROL=&H17, hwnd=Wordpad Edit Window Handle

`PostMessage hwnd, WM_CHAR, Asc("A"), 0`
and

```
 PostMessage hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VBA.vbKeyU,0
 PostMessage hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VBA.vbKeyU,0
```

But trying to send Control Key & a character ALL FAIL:

```
 PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, vbKeyControl, 0)
 PostMessage hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VBA.vbKeyU,0
 PostMessage hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VBA.vbKeyU,0
 PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, vbKeyControl, 0)
```

```
 PostMessage hwnd, &H112, &HF100, &H46
 PostMessage hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, Asc("H"),0
```

&h112=WM_SYSCOMMAND, &HF100=SC_KEYMENU, &H46='H'

```
 Dim tCurKB(255) As Byte, tInitKB(255)  As Byte
 Dim lThreadID As Long
 GetKeyboardState tInitKB(0)
 tCurKB(VK_CONTROL) = &H80
 SetKeyboardState tCurKB(0)
PostMessage hwnd,WM_CHAR, , 1, vbKeyControl
```

Although Excel responds to the Locked Control Key from the above Set KeyBoardState,
WordPad does not.

Comment: What do you mean with _But trying to send Control Key & a character ALL FAIL_? What excatly is it? For Control-U you need to select text first in order to see an effect. Though, you should see that the icon for _Underlining_ has been switched in any case. It might probably also be helpful to post the code where you determine `hWnd`.

Comment: AFAIK, you must use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) if you want to use 'modifier' keys like Ctrl - this [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401425/how-can-i-use-sendinput-function-in-vba-to-combine-keystrokes-for-chrome-window) might help with that

Comment: @JohnM: Right, that works. I just tried that, i.e. I set the state of Ctrl to pressed (KEYDOWN) with `SendInput`, then I used `PostMessage` to send an U and the selected text was underlined. The last step was to release Ctrl again.

Comment: @Storax I guess I'd imagined using `SendInput` for both the Ctrl and the U ... but if it works then it works ... thanks for testing it!!

Comment: @Storax `hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, WindowCaption) `
                          Get The designated Wordpad
             `hWnd = FindWindowEx(nLng, 0, "RICHEDIT50W", vbNullString)`
                          'Get WordPad EDIT Control
My thought is/was that sending the Control + U, for example, would set the Underline function for any subsequent text until another Control+U was sent.  IAE, none of the selected characters are underlined nor is the Underline function set.

Comment: @JohnM Perhaps, then, this is the answer - YOU CAN't DO THAT; that is, I cannot send a control key request to a specified window (as is my quest), only to the what the system believes is the most Recent window, such as can easily be done just using `Sendkeys`.  Can you confirm that, please.

Comment: You are correct AFAIK (though I suppose someone else might come along with a better solution in the next couple of days?!). Obviously you could also use [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) immediately prior to sending the Ctrl to maximise the chance that the appropriate window receives the message from `SendInput`, but that offers no guarantees ... and you could do that and then use `SendKeys` anyway if you wanted.

Comment: I think you both got it wrong. You do not send a `Ctrl` key to a window. You just set the status of the `Ctrl` key to pressed like `NumLock ` _On_. After that you can use `PostMessage` to send an `U` to whatever window you want. The system will interpret that as a Ctrl-U. If you send an second `U` to another window it will be a Ctrl-U again. Even if you use the keyboard yourself the stataus of the  `Ctrl` key is pressed and you will type everything with a `ctrl` in front although you did not press the `Ctrl` key yourself.

Comment: @Storax WordPad fails to respond to setting the status to ~Ctrl~ as described above using `SetKeyBoardState`.  Perhaps you are thinking of setting the status using different code?

Comment: @JoshuaR: Yes, I am not talking about `SetKeyBoardState`. Sorry, then I got the whole discussion wrong. As said, using `SendInput` to set the status of the `Ctrl` key to pressed, `PostMessage` to send an `u` and `SendInput` to set the status of `Ctrl` to released did the job for me and that's what I tested.

Comment: @Storax 
````
ki(o).dwType = INPUT_KEYBOARD 'shift down 
ki(o).wVK = VK_CONTROL 
ki(o + 1) = ki(o) ' key down 
ki(o + 1).wVK = VkKeyScan(Asc("A")) 'w/Cntl=SELECT ALL CMD 
ki(o + 2) = ki(o + 1) ' key up 
ki(o + 2).dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP 
ki(o + 3) = ki(o) ' shift up 
ki(o + 3).dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP 
o = o + 4 
SendInput(o - 1, ki(1), LenB(ki(1))), 
````
* `SendInput` Returns '4'
* 'err.lastdllerror' returns '5'
* `WordPad`, set as foreground window immediately prior is unaffected
* All code within the current VBE is selected - confirming the `Cntl` is received there

Comment: @JoshuaR: Sorry, I  don't understand your last comment

Comment: @Storax The `SendInput` function set the `Ctrl` followed by an "A", Select ALL Cmd.  This should have selected all of the text in the `ForeGround WordPad` window... however, the VBE window received the CMD & the code in that window was selected.  Closing the VBE, all of the Text was selected in the Excel window from which the `SendInput` Function was launched.  WordPad simply refuses to receive/recognize the `Ctrl` State it seems.

Comment: @JoshuaR: Ok, I see. Thta's the reason why I used `PostMessage` where you have control which window will be used. `SendInput` is not reliable in doing that. But you only have to use `SendInput` once to set the status of the `Ctrl` key to _pressed_. Then you can use `PostMessage` to send an `a` (Wordpad wil interpret it as `Ctrl-a`) and then you send an `u`  (= `Ctrl-u`) and the last step is to use `SendInput` again to release the `Ctrl` key.

Comment: @Storax What works is for the "Main" WordPad window having focus rather than the "Edit" (child) window.  Thanks for sticking through this...

Comment: @Storax Perhaps you should summarize your your solution as an an`Answer` ?