# Convert deprecated keybd_event to new SendInput in VBA

Tags: vba, windows, speech-recognition

I have this code below that sends a key combination, and I would like to update it to use SendInput instead, since keybd_event has been deprecated. It was crafted to be used with speech recognition, particularly Dragon Professional's advanced scripting commands. Also, I'm not only interested on traditional modifier keys, such as Shift or Control, but any key combination, such as "a & 9" or "F9 & F7" for use with AHK. I've found this to be much beyond my hacky and limited VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As _
Long, bScan As Long, ByVal Flag As Long, ByVal exInfo As Long) As Long
'Assign the values for the tab and alt keys to variables of your choosing (Though the format may be important)
Const VK_TAB = 9
Const VK_LMENU = 18
Sub Main
keybd_event(VK_LMENU,0,0,0)  'Hold down the Alt key
    Wait 0.1       'These waits are necessary at least on my machine
keybd_event(VK_TAB,0,0,0)  'Hold down the Tab key
    Wait 0.1
keybd_event(VK_TAB,0,2,0)  'Releases the Tab key
    Wait 0.1
keybd_event(VK_LMENU,0,2,0)  'Releases the Alt key
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76401425/5162073) would be helpful.